# Why does my home have a double slab in the basement?

Tags: concrete, slab

We recently got about 12 inches of water in our basement during some heavy rain. I've decided to put in a sump to prevent this in the future. I rented a breaker to get through the concrete. After breaking it up I returned the breaker and went to bed. The next day when I started digging it out I found about 6-8 inches of filler material (small rocks and such). Then I found another concrete slab. I now need to go rent the breaker again. Is there a purpose to having 2 slabs? It there anything I need to worry about before breaking into this second slab?

The house was originally built in 1920. The area I'm digging out is nowhere near a footing. It's almost the center of the house (low point and near water heater and boiler). The water that came in was clean water. I believe it was from the downspouts that are connected to a weeping tile system. My suspicion is the original slab was damaged and they just put filler material down and poured another slab on top.

Comment: Age of the house might help.  About the only reason for a double slab is the people were too lazy to dig out a bad/broken/cracked slab.  Just make sure it not a footing, but they should only be close(less than a foot) from a wall or under posts.

Comment: One other reason is there might have been a flood before.  Instead of breaking/cutting the old slab, some drain pipes might have been laid in stone with a new slab placed on top.  If those drain pipes are blocked now, it would lead to flooding(and maybe a harder problem to fix).

Comment: If there's filler material that drains freely between the two slabs, this might work just fine for a sump pump, even though it's fairly shallow...

Comment: The house was originally built in 1920. The area I'm digging out is nowhere near a footing. It's almost the center of the house (low point and near water heater and boiler). The water that came in was clean water. I believe it was from the downspouts that are connected to a weeping tile system. My suspicion is the original slab was damaged and they just put filler material down and poured another slab on top.

Answer (score 0):

It’s done like that because they may have decided to add toilets and other drains so instead of tearing it out, they added the pipe and filler rock to create another slab.